# call jquery popup with function call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, popup

After I submit form, below line opens a popup modal.

```
<input class="js__p_start" type="submit"  value="submit" name="submit"/>
```

I dont want to open popup after submitting form. After submiting the form ajax is used to post data to php. I want to open popup after succesful ajax requst.
Ajax code is as follows,

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hidden_form").submit(function(){
var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
var name = $("#name").val();


var dataString = 'mobile='+ mobile + '&name='+ name;

if(name=='')
{
alert("Please Enter your name");
}
else
{

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "file.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){

//I Want to call Popup here, so that popup will appear only after user properly entereed form fields

}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

here is JS file:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.simplePopup = function(event) {
var simplePopup = {
  settings: {
    hashtag: "#/",
    url: "popup",
    event: event || "click"
  },

  initialize: function(link) {
    var popup = $(".js__popup");
    var body = $(".js__p_body");
    var close = $(".js__p_close");
    var routePopup = simplePopup.settings.hashtag + simplePopup.settings.url;

    var cssClasses = link[0].className;

    if (cssClasses.indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
      cssClasses = cssClasses.split(" ");

      for (key in cssClasses) {
        if (cssClasses[key].indexOf("js__p_") === 0) {
          cssClasses = cssClasses[key]
        }
      };
    }

    var name = cssClasses.replace("js__p_", "");

    // We redefine the variables if there is an additional popap
    if (name !== "start") {
      name = name.replace("_start", "_popup");
      popup = $(".js__" + name);
      routePopup = simplePopup.settings.hashtag + name;
    };

    link.on(simplePopup.settings.event, function() {
      simplePopup.show(popup, body, routePopup);
      return false;
    });

    $(window).on("load", function() {
      simplePopup.hash(popup, body, routePopup);
    });

    body.on("click", function() {
      simplePopup.hide(popup, body);
    });

    close.on("click", function() {
      simplePopup.hide(popup, body);
      return false;
    });

    $(window).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        simplePopup.hide(popup, body);
      }
    });
  },


  centering: function(popup) {
    var marginLeft = -popup.width()/2;
    return popup.css("margin-left", marginLeft);
  },

  show: function(popup, body, routePopup) {
    simplePopup.centering(popup);
    body.removeClass("js__fadeout");
    popup.removeClass("js__slide_top");
    location.hash = routePopup;
    document.getElementById("menu_but").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("toTop").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("cbp-spmenu-s1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  },

  hide: function(popup, body) {
    popup.addClass("js__slide_top");
    body.addClass("js__fadeout");
    location.hash = simplePopup.settings.hashtag;
    document.getElementById("menu_but").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("toTop").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("cbp-spmenu-s1").style.visibility = "visible";
  },

  hash: function(popup, body, routePopup) {
    if (location.hash === routePopup) {
      simplePopup.show(popup, body, routePopup);
    }
  }
};


return this.each(function() {
  var link = $(this);
  simplePopup.initialize(link);
});
 };
})(jQuery);
```

Basically I am looking for some function call insidde AJAX success section to get popup modal.

Answer (score 0):

The function in js file is `immediately invoked function IIF` that is why it is executing by itself and you are seeing the pop up 
.

You need to remove the remove the parenthesis before and after the function expression to make it behave like normal function.
You can refractory this function as

```
function someFunctionName(){
    // you code goes here

}
```

Then in the ajax success block you can call `someFunctionName()`

Comment: what about this line? $.fn.simplePopup = function(event) {   
this line expects some event right? and again function name is changed so do we need to do some changes inside js?

Can you please paste complete JS function in above comment, that will be more clear and helpful.
thanks.

Comment: I tried but failed may be I am missing something.  Please post the edited script.

Comment: @Ritzor can create a plunker/jsfiddle.

Comment: plz do it, if it works I will accept answer, and will post that answer in original post

Comment: also see this code, this was on same html page, its a  call to that popup

'<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".js__p_start").simplePopup();
    });
  </script>'